# Linq to SQL select returns list within an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

The SQL that returns this result is below.

My linq to sql query returns an object, of concrete type "Credentials", that among other properties includes **List(of string) GradesList**. I have control over the *Credentials* type, and the query, but not the underlying database.

Here is what my return currently looks like:

```
Id  Code    IssueDate   ExpDate    Grd1 Grd2 Grd3 Grd4 Grd5 Grd6
6   TE0150  4/21/1999   4/21/2002   N    N    N    N    Y    Y
6   TE0150  3/11/2003   3/28/2007   N    N    N    N    Y    Y
6   TE0150  3/29/2012   3/28/2017   N    N    N    N    Y    Y
6   TE0140  5/3/2007    5/3/2008    Y    Y    Y    Y    N    N
6   TE0140  3/29/2012   3/28/2017   Y    Y    Y    Y    Y    Y
```

What I want is:

```
Id  Code    IssueDate   ExpDate    GradesList
6   TE0150  4/21/1999   4/21/2002   Grd5,Grd6 
6   TE0150  3/11/2003   3/28/2007   Grd5,Grd6
6   TE0150  3/29/2012   3/28/2017   Grd5,Grd6
6   TE0140  5/3/2007    5/3/2008    Grd1,Grd2,Grd3,Grd4
6   TE0140  3/29/2012   3/28/2017   Grd1,Grd2,Grd3,Grd4,Grd5,Grd6
```

Here is the SQL. The PPS_ENDORSE_DTL table has a column for each Grd level, with "Y" or "N" as a value.

```
from en     in PPS_ENDORSE_DTL
join jpi    in JPM_JP_ITEMS     on new { x1 = en.ACCOMPLISHMENT, x2 = en.DT_ISSUED }        equals new { x1 = jpi.JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID, x2 = jpi.EFFDT }
join jp     in JPM_PROFILE      on new { x1 = jpi.JPM_PROFILE_ID, x2 = en.EMPLID }          equals new { x1 = jp.JPM_PROFILE_ID, x2 = jp.EMPLID } 
join jci1   in JPM_CAT_ITEMS    on      en.PPS_ENDORSE_SUBJ                                 equals      jci1.JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID
join jci2   in JPM_CAT_ITEMS    on new { x1 = jpi.JPM_CAT_TYPE, x2 = jpi.JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID }  equals new { x1 = jci2.JPM_CAT_TYPE, x2 = jci2.JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID }
join es     in PPS_ENDORSE_SUB  on      jci1.JPM_CAT_ITEM_IDequals                          equals      es.PPS_ENDORSE_SUBJ
```

Comment: Is this actual Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities? Note that Linq-to-SQL is effectively obsolete at this point as it was last updated in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To that big inline linq statment, add

```
.AsEnumerable().Select(r => {
    var selectedGrades = new List();
    if (r.Grd1 == "Y") selectedGrades.Add("Grd1")
    if (r.Grd2 == "Y") selectedGrades.Add("Grd2")
    ...
    return new TypeWithGradesList{
         ....
         GradesList = string.Join(",", selectedGrades.ToArray())
    }
})
```

The `TypeWithGradesList is a model that has all the fields of your final result.

Comment: You might need to put `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.Select()` so the Linq environment doesn't complain that it cannot convert the lambda to actual SQL.

Comment: @Dai, possibly yes.  I thought inline linq returned `IEnumerable<T>`, but I usually use extension functions, so this is not a working memory for me.

Comment: Thank you. Sanity saved. One thing for the next person who may use this - the ".AsEnumerable()" before the ".Select(",  suggested by Dai,  was required to correct a "lambda expression... cannot be converted..." error, while using LinqPad. Thank you!

Comment: @Jazzy thanks for testing it out.  Updated to reflect the need for `.AsEnumerable()`.